# Do I need icc if I want to use ifort with f2py

Tags: f2py

I have Intel FORTRAN and want to use ifort to make a FORTRAN extension with f2py. I get an error message and was wondering whether this is because I need icc (Intel C compiler) as well.

Incidentally, f2py finds the compiler:
Found executable /usr/local/bin/ifort
But then throws an error ending with

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/**init**.py", line 430, in get_version
    raise CompilerNotFound()
numpy.distutils.fcompiler.CompilerNotFound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fcompiler needs to be specified as `--fcompiler=intelem` for 64 bit.
Now I get other errors on FORTRAN code that worked with gfortran on Python 3.6, but that is a different question.